# Tableau Adding tool tips to images

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am creating a landing page in Tableau which points to different dashboards that I created. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJzCZ.png). If you click on an image, you are redirected to the corresponding dashboard.

Now, I also want to add a tool tip for the image, which should include more information about the dashbord. I cannot figure out how to add custom tool tips to the images.

Does someone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image in a worksheet and include a tooltip there in the worksheet. Then add the worksheet to homepage. Also add 'goto sheet' action for the worksheet to navigate to the dashboard when click.